# Is MySql cluster data node storage a memory based?

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

I am reading some introduction pages about mySQL NDB storage engine. All of them saying NDB is an in-memory storage. Does this mean all the data are stored in memory? I think all the database data should be saved in data node storage and they should not be in memory. I believe there should be some part of the data which is cached in memory. So I want to understand what exactly in-memory storage mean? And where should the data be saved in, SQL node or data node?